# What's the right way to write this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I execute this query against my database:

**Code:**

```
SELECT TOP 20 
ha.datetime as ha_date, 
ha.id_hist_calls as ha_id_hist_calls, 
ha.name as ha_name, 
s.name as s_name, 
ss.name as ss_name 
FROM Hist_answer ha 
left join Hist_calls hc on hc.id_hist_calls = ha.id_hist_calls 
left join Service s on s.id_service = ha.from_id_service 
left join Service ss on ss.id_service = ha.id_service 

WHERE ha.id_hist_calls NOT IN ( 
SELECT 
ha.id_hist_calls as ha_id_hist_calls 
FROM Hist_answer ha 
WHERE ha.id_firm='39273' AND ha.datetime BETWEEN '2010.06.01 00:00:000' AND '2013.10.01 00:00:000' 
ORDER BY ha.datetime ASC 
) 

AND ha.id_firm='39273' 
AND ha.datetime BETWEEN '2010.06.01 00:00:000' AND '2013.10.01 00:00:000' 
ORDER BY ha.datetime ASC
```

I get this error:

```
Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.
```

How can I correct this select query?

Comment: It's right there in the error "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in subqueries". Just keep the last order by

Comment: @the_lotus: reading errors messages - you're demanding too much.

Comment: @the_lotus but if i remove order by datetime, get i aright sorting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the the ORDER BY clause from the subquery

```
SELECT TOP 20 
ha.datetime as ha_date, 
ha.id_hist_calls as ha_id_hist_calls, 
ha.name as ha_name, 
s.name as s_name, 
ss.name as ss_name 
FROM Hist_answer ha 
left join Hist_calls hc on hc.id_hist_calls = ha.id_hist_calls 
left join Service s on s.id_service = ha.from_id_service 
left join Service ss on ss.id_service = ha.id_service 

WHERE ha.id_hist_calls NOT IN ( 
SELECT 
ha.id_hist_calls as ha_id_hist_calls 
FROM Hist_answer ha 
WHERE ha.id_firm='39273' AND ha.datetime BETWEEN '2010.06.01 00:00:000' AND '2013.10.01 00:00:000' 
) 

AND ha.id_firm='39273' 
AND ha.datetime BETWEEN '2010.06.01 00:00:000' AND '2013.10.01 00:00:000' 
ORDER BY ha.datetime ASC
```

Comment: i aright understand - in lines WHERE ha.id_hist_calls NOT IN (....) not need use order by?

Comment: yes... no need for order by clauses in subqueries

Answer (score 1):

To expand a little on what others have said...

SQL is **set-based**, and sets are fundamentally unordered.

The `NOT IN subquery` doesn't care about the `subquery` order because it's a set-based operation. The DBMS might choose a specific physical order that provides best performance, but from the logical standpoint, order doesn't matter.

That's why there is no purpose in ordering the `subquery` - only the top ORDER BY will "stick" to make any difference to the client.

Comment: i aright understand - in lines `WHERE ha.id_hist_calls NOT IN (....)` not need use order by?

Comment: tanks for information +1 )